# Show profile2 fields on users page through panels

Tags: 7, panels, users

I would like to select profile2 fields on users page.

Elements:

- Profile2: artist + fields
- User: role artist

If the user is being viewed is an artist the panel should show its fields.

Actions:

- Created the profile2 for a custom user (if I do not panelize the user/%user page the user can view the profile2 fields).
- Activated the user_view pane
- Added relatioship with profile 2
- Now the profile2 fields appears on the UI.
- Select the field header_img
- Save the pane

I must have forgotten something because the profile (panelized) fields does not show any content of the profile2 fields..

Attaching some screenshots!

[image: relationship]
[image: fields]
[image: panelcontent]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are doing it ok, but there is an issue related that you can check at https://www.drupal.org/node/1011370#comment-9332247.

If you update to the latest dev version of profile2, it should work, and you could select the profile context and the profile type.